# Emacs lisp, succinct keymaps

Tags: emacs, elisp

On top of evil-mode in emacs, I have written an extension mode which allows me to insert mathematical and greek unicode characters in a single key-press. However the code looks like this (for hundreds of lines):

```
(define-key evil-unicode-state-map "a" "α")
(define-key evil-unicode-state-map "b" "β")
(define-key evil-unicode-state-map "g" "γ")
```

I am wondering if there is a preferred way of cutting out all the boilerplate?
Ideally I would be able to write something like the following:

```
(setq evil-unicode-state-map
  {"a" "α"
   "b" "β"
   "g" "γ"})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do it will be:

```
(setq my-evil-unicode-state-map
  '(("a" . "α")
    ("b" . "β")
    ("g" . "γ")))

(dolist (key-def my-evil-unicode-state-map)
  (let ((key (car key-def)) (def (cdr key-def)))
    (define-key evil-unicode-state-map key def)))
```

EDIT: (reflecting [Ivan Andrus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/152879/)'s comment)

If `my-evil-unicode-state-map` is not used elsewhere,

```
(dolist (key-def
         '(("a" . "α")
           ("b" . "β")
           ("g" . "γ"))))
  (define-key evil-unicode-state-map (car key-def) (cdr key-def)))
```

Comment: You can also just `let`-bind `my-evil-unicode-state-map` so that you don't have an extra global variable hanging around.

Comment: @IvanAndrus Thanks, you're right. I just wanted it to be as similar as possible to the template given in the question.